# How can I use the Conditional OR to search emails with imap_search - PHP IMAP library

Tags: php, email, imap

I need to use an OR statement in an imap_search() command.

I found that a condition OR is not supported in this library.  [Imap_search Bug Report Link](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45140) There has to be a way that I can search through the email using a conditional OR, how would I go about doing it?  I'm not sure where I'd start.

What I'd like to be able to do:

```
$boxes = imap_search($connection,'SINCE "08-Mar-2011" AND (BODY "bobby" OR BODY "robert" OR BODY "bob"');
```

Comment: Your `SEARCH` syntax is wrong, as the operations are prefix not infix.    Try `'SINCE "08-Mar-2011" (OR BODY "bobby" OR BODY "robert" BODY "bob")'` and see if it works...

Comment: Sorry to no avail - I even tried to add the last OR between "robert" and BODY, but still nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your SEARCH syntax is wrong, as the operators are prefix and not infix. The correct search string should be `'SINCE "08-Mar-2011" OR BODY "bobby" OR BODY "robert" BODY "bob"'`.

But if PHP simply doesn't support `OR` in `imap_search` -- and your link indicates that they don't, despite c-client support for it for almost 10 years -- then you'll have to do the conditional OR in your application.  Run

```
$box_bobby  = imap_search($connection, 'SINCE "08-Mar-2011" BODY "bobby"');
$box_robert = imap_search($connection, 'SINCE "08-Mar-2011" BODY "robert"');
$box_bob    = imap_search($connection, 'SINCE "08-Mar-2011" BODY "bob"');
```

and then merge the three result sets.

Comment: +1 for prefix/infix distinction. needed this for non-PHP application (ok, well, command-line management of my mailboxes using IMAP as a shell, because some of us like shells) and had never gotten a hang of the boolean operators.

Answer (score 1):

or use instead an array_merge to join the results in a single array:

```
//search codes: 1 -> FROM, 2 -> SUBJECT
array_push($filtri, array(1,"no-reply@accounts.google.com"));
array_push($filtri, array(1,"Tophost"));
array_push($filtri, array(2,"promemoria"));

$yesterday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime ("-1 days"));

foreach($filtri as $filtro){
    if ($filtro[0] == 1) $addFiltri = ' FROM "'.$filtro[1].'" ';
    if ($filtro[0] == 2) $addFiltri = ' SUBJECT "'.$filtro[1].'" ';
    $temp = imap_search($inbox,'SINCE "'.$yesterday.'" '.$addFiltri);
    $emails = array_merge($emails , $temp); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI on IMAP OR syntax, OR is a prefix operator and can only take **two** operands.

```
SINCE "08-Mar-2011" OR BODY "bobby" BODY "robert"'
```

If you have more than two, you need to add an OR:
e.g., 3 operands

```
SINCE "08-Mar-2011" OR OR BODY "bobby" BODY "robert" BODY "bob"'
```

e.g., 4 operands

```
SINCE "08-Mar-2011" OR OR OR BODY "bobby" BODY "robert" BODY "bob" BODY "bobert"'
```

Also, I saw in other posts that IMAP uses the polish syntax, so parens are not necessary.