# PHP imap_search on outlook365 server limits?

Tags: php, outlook, office365, imap, office365api

Related Post: [How can I use the Conditional OR to search emails with imap_search - PHP IMAP library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255763/how-can-i-use-the-conditional-or-to-search-emails-with-imap-search-php-imap-li)

I'm implementing a PHP script which uses `imap_search` to search through an outlook365 mailbox and retrieve emails which contain a certain subject (user ID).

I've got it working (code below) but I'm concerned that I have to issue a new `imap_search` command for each user ID (potentially hundreds). Moreover, I want to do this whole thing every 5 minutes.

I'm concerned that I'll get blacklisted / removed from outlook365 for this behaviour.

The root of the problem is that `imap_search` doesn't support the `OR` operator.

Here's my code:

```
// Assume we'll be inside a loop and "123" denotes a single customer ID.
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'SUBJECT "[123]" SINCE "2 March 2018"');
```

So in effect, I'll be doing this:

```
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'SUBJECT "[123]" SINCE "2 March 2018"');
// Do processing
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'SUBJECT "[124]" SINCE "2 March 2018"');
// Do processing
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'SUBJECT "[125]" SINCE "2 March 2018"');
...
```

What I'd **like** to do is:

```
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'SUBJECT "[123]" OR SUBJECT "[124]"... SINCE "2 March 2018"
```

Any clever ideas??

Edit: It looks like I'm going to have to call `imap_search` multiple times and concatenate the array. That's fine *but* **can anyone comment on whether or not this is likely to get me banned / throttled by Microsoft**?

Comment: The IMAP OR is a prefix operator.  OR (a) (b)

Comment: This isn't working. I've tried the following:
`'OR SUBJECT "[123]" SUBJECT "[456]" SINCE "2 March 2018"'`
`'OR (SUBJECT "[123]")(SUBJECT "[456]") SINCE "2 March 2018"'`
`'OR SUBJECT "[123]" SINCE "2 March 2018" SUBJECT "[456]" SINCE "2 March 2018"'`

`'OR OR SUBJECT "[123]" SUBJECT "[456]" SINCE "2 March 2018"'`

Comment: `'(SUBJECT "[123]" SINCE "2 March 2018") OR (SUBJECT "[456]" SINCE "2 March 2018")'`

Comment: I would try `SINCE "2 March 2018" OR (SUBJECT "123") (SUBJECT "456")`, but it also quite possible that Office365' search facility is just kind of broken, which is not uncommon with services that are not primarily IMAP.