# IMAP search for multiple SUBJECTS?

Tags: imap

I want to do an IMAP search that searches for multiple SUBJECT matches.

If I do the search below - I get the results I need:

```
SUBJECT "Transfer code" SINCE ...
```

Same for this one:

```
SUBJECT "Transfercode" SINCE ...
```

However if I try to combine them, I get **no results**:

```
SUBJECT "Transfer code" OR SUBJECT "Transfer code" SINCE ...
```

I have tried every possible variant, but **none of them work**:

```
SUBJECT "Transfer code" OR SUBJECT "Transfercode" SINCE ...
OR SUBJECT "Transfer code" OR SUBJECT "Transfercode" SINCE ...
(SUBJECT "Transfer code" OR SUBJECT "Transfercode") ...
SUBJECT Transfer code OR SUBJECT Transfercode SINCE ...
```

Anyone knows how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using PHP Imap_search, and apparently the "OR" operator is not supported.

You'll need to search multiple times, and merge the results - as discussed in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5264230/776264

Comment: Also, the proper use of `OR` is as a prefix operator: `OR A B` or `OR (A) (B)`, where A and B are sub searches.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Max's comment (since I lack the points), OR is a prefix operator and can only take **two** operands (not three).  So the code should be:

```
SINCE "08-Mar-2011" OR SUBJECT "Transfer code" SUBJECT "Transfercode"'
```

If you have more than two, you need to add an OR:
e.g., 3 operands

```
SINCE "08-Mar-2011" OR OR SUBJECT "Transfer code" SUBJECT "Transfercode" SUBJECT "Xfer code"'
```

e.g., 4 operands

```
SINCE "08-Mar-2011" OR OR OR SUBJECT "Transfer code" SUBJECT "Transfercode" SUBJECT "Xfer code" SUBJECT "Xfercode"'
```